# File upload using only password/username credentials to a non-API endpoint

Tags: python, authentication, http-headers

I'm trying to upload a file via python. 
 I looked [HERE](https://xfilesharingpro.docs.apiary.io/#reference/upload) because I think the site uses this system. The problem is that both by using cookies and classic authentication (username/password) the file is not uploaded to my personal account, but only generically on the site. I don't want to use the API because I saw that some programs only use classic credentials for this site

```
import requests

# URL for uploading the file
upload_url = 'https://w100-worldbytez.com/cgi-bin/upload.cgi'

# Data of the file to upload
file_data = open('file.txt', 'rb')

# Session cookies
cookies = {
    'xfss': 'lo5gztetvxxxxxxx',  # Replace with your xfss value
}

# Execute the upload request
response = requests.post(upload_url, files={'file': file_data}, cookies=cookies)

# Close file
file_data.close()

# Print the answer
print(response.text)
```

I take a look to Headers and Fetch/XHR from Network tab (Dev Tools) and also upload.js file from upload form page but I can't see the way to upload files setting only the username and password. 
Any idea to solve ?

It could be that the URL is incorrect because the problem is that the file is uploaded to the site, but not to my personal account